# Tener una fila por defecto en tabla dinamica

Tags: html, jquery, botón, while, tablas

Tengo una tabla dinamica que tiene botones para agregar y eliminar filas que funciona correctamente. Lo que le falta es **tener una fila por defecto** porque inicialmente la tabla aparece vacia asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado hacer los `td` normales(es decir sin la funcion -`agregarFila`-) en la primera parte del tbody.

```
<!-- fila por defecto de la tabla -->
                                <th><select required class="col-12 form-control mr-sm-2 " name="materia[]" onchange="cambioOpciones();">
                                        <option disabled selected value=""> - Seleccione - </option>
                                        <?php
                                        while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_materia)) {
                                        ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>" data-nombre="<?php echo $datos['nombre'] ?>">
                                                <?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?> </option>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </select></th>
                                <th><input required type="text" name="nombre[]" class="form-control mr-sm-2 " disabled></th>
                                <th> <input name="cantidad[]" required class="form-control mr-sm-2   col-sm-3 col-md-12" type="number" min="0" max="1000000" list="cantidades">
                                    <datalist id="cantidades">

                                        <option value="10">

                                        <option value="100">

                                        <option value="1000">

                                        <option value="10000">

                                    </datalist>

                                    <div class="invalid-feedback"> Debe elegir una cantidad </div>
                                </th>
```

La fila se muestra por defecto en la tabla pero No funciona, debido a que en cada fila tengo un `select` que hace uso de un `while` y como es una estructura de control que no puede repetirse, en la segunda fila(apartir de donde se implementa la funcion -`agregarFila`- )no se muestran los resultados que trae el `while` al `select`.

Otra cosa que he intentado es meter el while en una función y usarla en las dos partes de tbody de la tabla; es decir en la "fila por defecto" y en las filas que se crean apartir del boton `agregar fila`. Tampoco surte efecto,en la primera fila se traen todos los registros necesarios en el select mas en la  segunda no.

A continuación mostraré el codigo completo de la tabla  incluyendo la funcion `agregarFila`

```
<table class="table">
                            <thead class="thead-light ">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Codigo</th>
                                    <th>Nombre</th>
                                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                                <!-- fila por defecto de la tabla -->
                                <th><select required class="col-12 form-control mr-sm-2 " name="materia[]" onchange="cambioOpciones();">
                                        <option disabled selected value=""> - Seleccione - </option>
                                        <?php
                                        while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_materia)) {
                                        ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>" data-nombre="<?php echo $datos['nombre'] ?>">
                                                <?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?> </option>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </select></th>
                                <th><input required type="text" name="nombre[]" class="form-control mr-sm-2 " disabled></th>
                                <th> <input name="cantidad[]" required class="form-control mr-sm-2   col-sm-3 col-md-12" type="number" min="0" max="1000000" list="cantidades">
                                    <datalist id="cantidades">

                                        <option value="10">

                                        <option value="100">

                                        <option value="1000">

                                        <option value="10000">

                                    </datalist>

                                    <div class="invalid-feedback"> Debe elegir una cantidad </div>
                                </th>

                                <!-- script donde sea crean filas apartir del boton agregarFila -->
                                <script>
                                    var myTable = document.querySelector("table");

                                    function agregarFila() {

                                        var row = myTable.insertRow(myTable.rows.length);
                                        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                                        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                                        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

                                        cell1.innerHTML = `<select required class="col-12 form-control mr-sm-2 "
                                            name="materia[]" onchange="cambioOpciones();">
                                            <option disabled selected value=""> - Seleccione - </option>
                                            <?php while ($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_materia)) {
                                            ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>" data-nombre="<?php echo $datos['nombre'] ?>">
                                            <?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?> </option>
                                         <?php } ?>
                                             </select>`;
                                        cell2.innerHTML = '<input required type="text"  name="nombre[]"  class="form-control mr-sm-2 " disabled >';
                                        cell3.innerHTML = `<input name="cantidad[]" required class="form-control mr-sm-2  col-sm-3 col-md-12" placeholder="Ingrese cantidad"   id="cantidad" type="number" min="0" max="1000000" list="cantidades">
                                            <datalist id="cantidades">

                                                <option value="10">

                                                <option value="100">

                                                <option value="1000">

                                                <option value="10000">

                                            </datalist> <div class="invalid-feedback"> Debe elegir una cantidad </div>`;;

                                    }


                                    function eliminarFila() {
                                        var rowCount = myTable.rows.length;
                                        if (rowCount <= 2) {
                                            alert('No se puede eliminar el encabezado , debe haber al menos un ingrediente para crear la receta');
                                        } else {
                                            myTable.deleteRow(rowCount - 2);
                                        }

                                    }
                                    //  AUTOCOMPLETADO DE NOMBRE
                                    function cambioOpciones() {
                                        //el evento siempre esta disponible en la función
                                        //event.target -> elemento que disparó el evento ( select name= materia)
                                        let sel = event.target;
                                        //definir valor inicial
                                        let value = '';
                                        //si se selecciona una opción...
                                        if (event.target.value) {
                                            //tomar el nombre desde el atributo data-nombre de la opción seleccionada
                                            value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].dataset.nombre;
                                        }
                                        // Obtener fila a la que pertenece el select
                                        let tr = sel.closest('tr');
                                        // Obtener campo desde TR, por atributo name y asignar valor
                                        tr.querySelector('[name="nombre[]"]').value = value;

                                    }
                                </script>


                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```